# Random Hankel matrix and eigenvalues distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I would like to know if there are any theoretical results on the distribution of the eigenvalues of [Hankel matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix). I seek a result like the [Marchenko–Pastur distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution) for random matrices.

Comment: This is studied in the paper by Bryc, Dembo, Jiang (Annals of probability 2006).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there are no known results regarding extremal eigenvalues.

The only concrete result I know of regarding the density of states of random Hankel matrices is the following:

> ([Bose and Sen, 2006](http://www.isical.ac.in/~statmath/html/publication/spectral2.pdf)) For a Hankel matrix constructed from i.i.d. standard Gaussians, the limiting density of states is a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 2/3.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i have seen this article. I am looking for the min and max of the eigenvalues.

Comment: That's as much as I know... good luck hunting!